# Finding a King and a Queen in 3 Cards

Tags: probability, card-games

I'm looking at a problem for a card game where you already have a king in hand and need to find a king and a queen when drawing 3 cards. Right now I'm looking at something like:

$3! \times \frac{3}{51} \times \frac{4}{50}$

But I am pretty sure that this is not correct, as the order matters if the king or queen is found first because the chance of finding either is not the same.

EDIT: For simplicity's sake, let's assume that the only card not in the deck is the one king in hand. Also, the third card does not matter and is allowed to be another king or queen or any other card.

Comment: Do you need exactly one king and exactly one queen, or is a draw of two queens and one king acceptable?  Do you have a card in hand besides the king?

Comment: @RossMillikan The third card is irrelevant so it could be a king or a queen. For this example, the only card not in the deck is the one king in hand.

Comment: If other players have some of the cards, you would have to know what those cards are in order to give a simple answer.

Comment: @JMoravitz:  I read it that he already has one king, then draws three more cards which must include another king and a queen.

Comment: As OP is talking about "ordering" issue, the question may be related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795466/how-do-i-know-when-to-take-ordering-into-account/2795496#2795496

Comment: @RossMillikan looking over it again, I agree with your reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close but you double count all draws of $KKQ$ or $KQQ$ twice, once for each of the paired cards.  You need to subtract those once, so it becomes $$3!\cdot \frac 3{51}\cdot \frac 4{50}-3\cdot \frac 3{51}\cdot \frac 4{50}\cdot \frac 2{49}-3\cdot \frac 3{51}\cdot \frac 4{50}\cdot \frac 3{49}$$

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the probability that *at least* one from seven favoured cards will be among the next three cards drawn from the fifty-one cards remaining?   The complement of this event is that none from the seven will be drawn when drawing three from fifty one.

> $$1-\frac{\binom 7 0\binom {51-7}3}{\binom {51}3}$$

Do you want the probability that at least one from three(remaining) kings *and* at least one from four queens will be among the next three cards drawn from the fifty-one cards remaining?   The principle of inclusion and exclusion will be used.

> $$1-\frac{\binom 3 0\binom {51-3}3}{\binom {51}3}-\frac{\binom 4 0\binom {51-4}3}{\binom {51}3}+\frac{\binom 7 0\binom {51-7}3}{\binom {51}3}$$

Comment: I read it as that the OP wants both a king *and* a queen, not a king *or* a queen in the next three cards.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for a king and a queen

Answer (score 0):

There are 6 in total- (KQN,KNQ,NKQ)x2 with K,Q interchanged.

Now we have to avoid double counting. So -

$$P(KQN) = \frac{3}{51}. \frac{4}{50} $$
$$P(QKN) = \frac{4}{51}. \frac{3}{50} $$
$$P(KNQ) = \frac{3}{51} .\frac{46}{50}. \frac{4}{49}$$
$$P(QNK) = \frac{4}{51} .\frac{47}{50}. \frac{3}{49}$$
 Any of 50 card except the queens/kings for 2nd pick.
$$P(NKQ) = \frac{44}{51}.\frac{3}{50} .\frac{4}{49}$$ 
$$P(NQK) = \frac{44}{51}.\frac{4}{50} .\frac{3}{49}$$ 
Any of 51 cards excpet kings and queens for 1st pick.

$$P(total) = \sum_{all} P = \frac{279*3*4}{51*50*49}$$

(This turns to be same as Ross's answer)